# Create Menu on CreateConnection GEF

Tags: java, contextmenu, eclipse-gef

I want to create a context menu when I create and finish the Connection between two editParts,
because I want to select some feature for the connection.
How can I create a contextMenu or a popup menu in an Editpart without clicking the right button?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the `setTargetAnchor(ConnectionAnchor)` method of your `Connection` implementation, e.g.:

```
PolylineConnection connection = new PolylineConnection() {
  @Override
  public void setTargetAnchor(ConnectionAnchor anchor) {
    super.setTargetAnchor(anchor);
    if (anchor == null)
      return;
    // create menu
  }
};
```